# Are asynchronous distributed systems faster than synchronous?

Tags: networking, blockchain, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I'm doing some cursory research on distributed systems, relating to blockchain and consensus and I was wondering what the advantages of using an async system vs sync.

Is it faster? More secure? What reasons go into designing one system over another?

Answer (score 1):

A synchronous distributed system isn't practical - you are assuming the network is perfect, and delivers messages within some time bound. If you can make that assumption, perhaps in a datacenter network, then designing a synchronous distributed algorithm will be much cheaper than an asynchronous equivalent. However, as soon as the assumption breaks, you must use an asynchronous algorithm, lest you lose the safety properties you want.